# Can someone explain this weird Windows 10 File Explorer behaviour?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have the problem (which I think is a feature that everyone has) that in File Explorer in Windows 10 sometimes selects files and sometimes drag and drops files, when I drag and drop on files. Not a huge issue but sometimes frustrating when I quickly want to drag and drope files around.

[Here's a video that shows the problem](https://streamable.com/w07rf)

Comment: Nothing strange about that. Literally every version of Windows I’ve ever used worked like that.

Answer (score -1):

Went onto discord and asked people on there the same question.. turns out that when dragging on text causes drag and drop and dragging on the whitespace (still on the list element) anywhere where there isn't text causes selecting